# Selected drop down menu in simple_form when f.association is present in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, simple-form

Can you please tell me if there is a way using simple_form with Rails, when you have "f.associations" present in a view, to disable the selected drop down menu in the form but still use the prefilled value of the field?

I have tried with option ":disabled => true" but it disables the whole text field and a I need a value to be present here. When I submit the form I receive an error that a value should be present.

I have tried with  option ":as => :hidden", the input value does not appear, but when I submit the form I receive an error that a value should be present.

I have tried with option ":readonly => true", but drop down menu still appears. It appears grayed out but can still be selected.

Thank you,
Silviu

Answer (score 0):

Use input hidden with same variable and value for f.assocation disabled, when submit form, the needing value will be sended at once time.

Sample code illustrate the case, note line `f.association :company` get the value `company_id` but not send, so the `f.input :company_id` will replace, and works!

```
Welcome to project railstrace !
<p>Simple Form content: </p>
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: save_path, :method => :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :email %>
  <%= f.association :company, disabled: true %>
  <%= f.input :company_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @user.company_id} %>
  <%= f.association :roles %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: The code in the form addapted: ` <div class="card-body">  
                       <div class="form-inputs">
                            <%= f.association profile, disabled: true, :selected => params[:profile_id], label: 'Profile' %>
                            <%= f.input : profile_name, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => :profile_name } %> `  . if I try to Submit the form, same thing: "profile must exist". In my case I have 2 tables, "profile" that  has_many  "profile_members".

Comment: To debug the needing values, first not add f.input hidden and f.association is not disabled. Then run submit and see these values (from f.assocation) in command line console, or run command `Rails.logger.debug variable` (and view in /log/development.log) as destination of submit form. After know these values, you can begin add and config f.input! If you can't, add my skype xprotoprotox, I will help you!

Comment: I followed your advice and I saw what it was needed. Now is working like you suggested. Thank you very much for the information!

Comment: Congrat! It calls "success" + "full"!